# Necessary Sufficient Conditions for Almost sure convergence

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

$X_n$ is an i.i.d. sequence and let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

(a) Prove that $(S_n-C_n)/n\rightarrow0$ almost surely for some real sequence $\{C_n\}$ if and only $E(|X_1|)<\infty$ and in that case $C_n/n\rightarrow E(X_1)$.

(b) Assume $E(X_1)=1$ and $\{a_n\}$ is a real bounded sequence. Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i/n\rightarrow 1$ almost surely if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^na_i/n\rightarrow 1$.

Give some hints about how to approach these kinds of problems. I need to know only the basic ideas and not the detailed proof, so that I may try myself, using those ideas. I tried to use some version of law of large numbers, but failed.

Comment: Hint: Borel Cantelli